# Prove that $T$ has at most two distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, generalized-eigenvector

I need help with a problem in Axler's Linear Algebra text.
Any hint would be great.

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$, and $T: V\to V.$ If $$\dim \ker(T^{n-2}) \neq \dim \ker(T^{n-1}),$$ then prove that $T$ has at most two distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411534/prove-t-has-at-most-two-distinct-eigenvalues?rq=1 seems highly relevant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $T$ has at most two distinct eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411534/prove-t-has-at-most-two-distinct-eigenvalues)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the information given to conclude that the the Jordan canonical form of $T$ has a Jordan block associated with $0$ of size at least $n-1$.